# convert very big int (written as string) to binary string in c/c++

Tags: c++, c

I have a number in base 10 which has around 10k digits. I want to convert it into base 2 (1010101001...). All I can think of is primitive algorithm:

`take last digit mod 2 -> write down bit`

`number divide by 2;`

It's shouldn't be hard to implement primary school division on string, but i'm thinking that it very inefficiente. If i'm right it will be `O(l^2)`, where `l` means length of number in base 10. Can that be done faster?

Comment: It's the divisions that are slow. Divide by 2^32 at each step, and do 32 bits at a time.

Comment: still makes it l^2 just with 1/32 constant. Which not helps too much since I give an example 10k digit is small I will have 10m digits or even 100m to deal with. I'm almost sure there must be n logn approach

Comment: There's an O(1) approach. Data doesn't just appear out of thin air, it's created by *something*. Find out where this 10 KB string came from and make them generate an array of integers instead of an array of characters.

Answer (score 1):

From what I understand you have your big number represented as a sequence of decimal digits. If that is so, you can compute a "binary" representation using multiplication and addition:

> value = sum(i in 0...n-1) 10<sup>i</sup> * digit<sub>i</sub>

This computation can be split into parts in a divide and conquor way, although I'm not sure if you can arrive at a O(n log n) algorithm.

Answer (score 1):

If you are working with big numbers, I really suggest you use a multi precision library. Try GMP or MPRF or something similar. 
-Øystein

Answer (score 1):

Division by 2 is the same as multiplication by 1/2.  For the latter you can use some of the well known fast multiplication algorithms (Toom–Cook, Schönhage–Strassen,etc).